# Rails 4: SASS background image works locally, fails in AWS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services

Just updated to Rails 4 and now this style, which in history worked everywhere, and now only works locally:

```
#subfooter {
    width: 1160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 45px 0 20px;
    background: url(ap@1x.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

It fails in AWS. Anyone have any ideas about SASS/CSS loaded image differences across environments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because on production you can not use assets with direct url as they are compiled. So to resolve your issue you must do it like this instead:

```
#subfooter {
    width: 1160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 45px 0 20px;
    background: url(image_path("ap@1x.png")) no-repeat top left;
}
```

I hope this will answer your question.

Comment: Thank-you so much! Couldn't figure it out. Cheers!